# How to add custom id attribute in radio button cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp

i have to make 7 radio buttons according to days but this is generating common id all the time . i want different id's for all the radios according to days.

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('', array('type' => 'post', 'class' => 'form form-horizontal', 'id'=>'addDeliveryPereferenceForm', 'novalidate')); ?>

<?php echo $this->Form->control('delivery_preference[]', ['type' => 'radio', 'label' => false, 'class' => 'form-control border-primary','id'=>'mon','options' => $preferences]); ?>

<?php echo $this->Form->control('delivery_preference[]', ['type' => 'radio', 'label' => false, 'class' => 'form-control border-primary','id'=>'mon','options' => $preferences]); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

How does $preferences look like ? If you could modify it to something like this, it will work. You can also add other attributes to each option created here. You should also remove the id from your code to avoid conflict.

```
$preferences = [
    ['value' => 1, 'text' => 'monday', 'id' => 'mon'],
    ['value' => 2, 'text' => 'tuesday', 'id' => 'tue'],
    ['value' => 3, 'text' => 'wednesday', 'id' => 'wed'],
    ['value' => 4, 'text' => 'thursday', 'id' => 'thu'],
    ['value' => 5, 'text' => 'friday', 'id' => 'fri']
];
```

[FormHelper from cookbook](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#using-collections-to-build-options)